# CakePHP how to get multiple rows by array of ID's

Tags: database, cakephp

I would like to pull from database multiple rows, according to a list of array of ID's.

In some other frameworks there seem to be something like "WHERE_IN", but not here.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

I would like to know how to do that through the find() or read() (or any other cakephp function) and NOT build a query manually, since I want all data to be escaped and secure.

thank you

Comment: Thank you for your question, i was preparing my self to code some monstrosity before i googled this :D.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to ["Complex Find Functions"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) (third example) this should work:

```
$this->YourModel->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "YourModel.id" => array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    )
));
```

Comment: to do the same but  with id different of array?

Comment: @Martin: thank you for the question. I'm not sure what you mean - do you want to select records whose IDs are not in the array like the `NOT IN`-operator? Or do you want to select using another field than `id`

Comment: I already solved the doubt, thanks anyway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508682/find-where-id-is-not-in-array-of-ids/14509011#14509011

Comment: On CakePHP 3 this throws *InvalidArgumentException: Cannot convert value to integer*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the newer CakePHPs you need to specify 'IN'.  This solves aexl question.

```
$this->YourModel->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        "YourModel.id IN" => [1, 2, 3, 4]
    ]
]);
```