# Find where id is not in array of ids

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

To find id whose value is equal to the id of an array of ids:

```
$this->YourModel->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "YourModel.id" => array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    )
));
```

How I can do the opposite, find elements where the ids are different than an array of ids?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should work:

```
$this->YourModel->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "NOT" => array( "YourModel.id" => array(1, 2, 3, 4) )
    )
));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Comment: I'm using CakePHP 2.10 and this results in a DB error:
SELECT `Division`.`division_id`, `Division`.`id` FROM `divisions` AS `Division` LEFT JOIN `division_types` AS `DivisionType` ON (`Division`.`division_type_id` = `DivisionType`.`id`) WHERE NOT (`Division`.`id` IN (1, 142, 143, 144, 168, 178, 18....