# How to find fields by an array which contains multiple values by using like %% search

Tags: php, cakephp, find

I am trying to get multiple fields which match to those ids(1, 2, 3) by Like %% search.
I have tried to make it work for two hours, but it hasn't worked though it looks pretty simple.

```
$ids = array ('1','2','3');

$result = $this -> Model -> find ('all', array(
    'conditions' => array( 'Model.category LIKE' => '%'.$ids.'%')
));
```

I need somebody's help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP how to get multiple rows by array of ID's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819865/cakephp-how-to-get-multiple-rows-by-array-of-ids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, and thank you for answering my question. As long as I read your answers, the ansewer Nick Zinger posted was the most helpful. However, what I'd like to do was AND search. So I improved the answer like bellow.

```
$ids = array ('1','2','3');
$conditions = array();
foreach($ids as $id){
    $conditions['AND'][] = array( 'Model.category LIKE' => '%'.$id.'%')
}

$result = $this->Model->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions));
```

Again, I really appreciate for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you build the 'conditions' array separately. For example:

```
$ids = array ('1','2','3');
$conditions = array();
foreach($ids as $id){
    $conditions['OR'][] = array( 'Model.category LIKE' => '%'.$id.'%')
}

$result = $this->Model->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions));
```

Answer (score 0):

See [CakePHP how to get multiple rows by array of ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819865/cakephp-how-to-get-multiple-rows-by-array-of-ids)

```
$this->YourModel->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        "YourModel.id" => array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    )
));
```

Comment: This will not perform LIKE search

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but try it like

```
'Model.category LIKE' => "%$ids%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Havent tested it but this should work

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3);

$result = $this->Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.category'=>$ids ')
        ));
```