# getting value from string array in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

If I have this output of an array :

```
$array_to_delete =
[ 
    (int) 3 => (int) 4,
    (int) 4 => (int) 5 
]
```

And i want to get 4 and 5 and so on at where condition , Like that :

```
 $warehouseItemsData = $this->WarehouseEmployers->WarehouseItems->find()
    ->where(['id', $array_to_delete])
    ->all();
```

How can i do that ? in cake php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP how to get multiple rows by array of ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819865/cakephp-how-to-get-multiple-rows-by-array-of-ids)

Answer (score 1):

use IN

```
$warehouseItemsData = $this->WarehouseEmployers->WarehouseItems->find()
    ->where(['id IN', $array_to_delete])
    ->all();
```